# cannot open display from macos client with openvpn

Tags: macos, ssh, openvpn, x-server

I am trying to connect to a redhat server from a macos client, using ssh and openvpn. Command line commands work fine (eg vim), but displays dont get displayed, eg while running firefox or gvim, and I get the error:

```
No protocol specified
E233: cannot open display
```

I did "xhost +" and "export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority" on the macos client, and "export DISPLAY=:0.0" on the redhat server, but that did not solve the problem.

However, it is working when the client is ubuntu, so I guess the problem is on the macos client side.

BTW, when I run ssh after I did "xhost +", I get the warning:

```
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
```

Any suggestions on how to get displays working with macos client?

(I had posted this question on stackoverflow(68483620), but it was suggested there that I ask this question here.)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384725): instead of doing "ssh -X", do "ssh -Y". This is the short solution (which worked for me on Catalina + XQuartz), other longer solutions are also provided at this link.